# How to convert Series into DataFrame preserving the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large `DataFrame` with the following contents:

```
obj0   type  obj1    counts
car    P     wheel   2
tree   P     branch  5
box    I     ball    23
wheel  P     bus     3
grass  A     cow     10
...
```

I want to see how many `obj0` and `type` pairs I have, I do:
`obj0_sums = pdf.groupby(['obj0', 'type'])['counts'].sum()`.

```
obj0   type
car    P     5
tree   P     15
box    I     50
...
```

Then I need to do other operations on `obj0_sums` later but it is a `Series` where `obj0` and `type` columns have turned into the first row. How can I make it stay a `DataFrame` and preserve columns after `groupby` operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
In [262]: df.groupby(['obj0', 'type'], as_index=False)['counts'].sum()
Out[262]:
    obj0 type  counts
0    box    I      23
1    car    P       2
2  grass    A      10
3   tree    P       5
4  wheel    P       3
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> **as_index :** boolean, default True
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only
> relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for

```
pdf.groupby(['obj0', 'type'], as_index=False)['counts'].sum()
```